# how to convert curl request (-g) to python requests

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, ssl, curl, glob

i have a curl request with option -g its working but i am not able to access that with python requests.

```
curl -i -g -k -X POST -d '{"password": "pwd", "username": "test"}' https://ip_address:port/path/to/api
```

response is success with the details in requested.
also if i remove -g from above curl thre request is failing so form my app -g is mandatory.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

>>> r = requests.post("https://[ip_address]:port/path/to/api", auth=("test", "pwd"), body='')
```

error as ssl_cerificate failure.

how i can work with requests to get my response successfully.

Comment: Have you tried adding `verify=False` to your request?

Comment: yes, with verify=false its asking for certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this we need to import an additional lib/module as below

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning 
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

from now onwards you will not see the above issue